# LINQ return value conversion failed from string to int

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq, t-sql, sql-order-by

Hello there so I have a DropDownBox in vb.net which is field Type: Varchar in MS SQL Server 2012 and shows like this:

```
1 - Info 
10.1 - Testing
10.2 - Programs
2 - Modes
3 - Qualifications
....
```

But it shows in the wrong order. This is the code I got:

```
 Public Shared Function GetLineCodeList() As IEnumerable

        Dim _Result As IEnumerable

              _Result = (From lc As SLBLINECODE In DataManager.SlbContext.SLBLINECODES
                   Where lc.HIDDEN = 0
                   Order By lc.LINECODE
                   Select New With {
          .LINECODE = lc.LINECODE,
          .LINEDESCRIPTION = lc.LINECODE + " - " + lc.LINEDESCRIPTION
          }).ToList()

        Return _Result
    End Function
```

So I been trying to do a Order By CInt(lc.LINECODE)
Because I know Oracle works fine, but in T-SQL don't behave the same. Any recommendations ?

Comment: What is the database type of `LINECODE` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`Convert.ToInt32(lc.LINECODE)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx) or maybe due to `10.1` try [`Convert.ToDecimal(lc.LINECODE)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9z3s65(v=vs.110).aspx). There are more conversion methods [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `Convert` class.

**UPDATE #1**

What seems a better solution is to forget the order at the DB side.

Instead before calling `.ToList()` call `.OrderBy(item => Decimal.Parse(item.LINECODE))`.

In VB.NET: `.OrderBy(Function(item) Decimal.Parse(item.LINECODE))`

**UPDATE #2**

@Keyur PATEL is right. I also suggested to forget the ordering at the DB side but missed that an extra call to `.ToList()` is needed.

So what should work looks like this:

```vb
_Result =
    (
        From lc As SLBLINECODE In DataManager.SlbContext.SLBLINECODES
        Where lc.HIDDEN = 0
        Order By lc.LINECODE
        Select New With {
            .LINECODE = lc.LINECODE,
            .LINEDESCRIPTION = lc.LINECODE + " - " + lc.LINEDESCRIPTION
        }
    ) _
    .ToList() _
    .OrderBy(Function(item) Decimal.Parse(item.LINECODE)) _
    .ToList()
```

Comment: I tried this:     `Where lc.HIDDEN = 0
                   Select New With {
          .LINECODE = lc.LINECODE
          }).OrderBy(Function(lc) Decimal.Parse(lc.LINECODE)).ToList()`
but I get : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal Parse(System.String)'

same message for `Order By Convert.ToDecimal(lc.LINECODE)`

Comment: @JoelJacobson A little longer, but you could try `ToList()` before ordering, so it loads the list into memory first. The result is a longer and perhaps slightly ugly line, but might work: `Where lc.HIDDEN = 0 Select New With { .LINECODE = lc.LINECODE }).ToList().OrderBy(Function(lc) Decimal.Parse(lc.LINECODE)).ToList()` The last `ToList()` is only if you want to return a list.

Comment: thank you it works with the changes  thank you Keyur Patel and Gabor.